# Comparing account.parentId SOQL

Tags: soql, hierarchy, parent

Is it possible to to compare the parent id of an account to another account? i.e.

```
SELECT Id from Account WHERE child_account.parentId = parent_account.Id;
```

I keep getting the 'Unknown Error parsing query' message from the Query Editor.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot compare a field to another field in SOQL. The standard workaround is to use a formula. It's hard to tell what you're trying to achieve based on your syntax, but if you wanted to filter on records where one field equals another, you would do make a formula (say `DoesField1EqualField2__c`) that looks like:

```
Field1__c = Field2__c
```

And then in your query, filter on that:

```
SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE DoesField1EqualField2__c = true
```

Comment: I've adjusted the syntax in my most recent edit.

Comment: @KaiTribble So in your case `Field1__c` would be replaced with `ParentId` and `Field2__c` would be replaced with `Parent.Id`. Though I'm not sure how you think these two values could ever differ.

Comment: Neither do I. However, there is a corresponding validation rule that has this criteria listed: if(child_account.id != parent_account). Note they are both accounts, so they aren't in a master-detail relationship.

Answer (score 1):

try,

```
[SELECT Id from account where child_accountId = :parent_account];
```

Since both child account Id and Parent_account are on account object, you can compare.
parent_account is a variable that holds parent account Id. It will be assigned as follows,

```
string parent_account = account.accountId;
```